# How to model country, state and cities using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm a building a registration form for my website(it is using Neo4j) and need to populate the country, state and city field. All these fields are inter-linked i.e depending on country, state field will be set and depending on state city will be set. I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach to model this using Neo4j. Do I need to create nodes for each country, state and city, and then create relationships between all of them? For instance, Detroit - belongs to - Michigan - belongs to - United States. What would be the best approach to handle this in Neo4j? Are there any examples to look at ? Would it be efficient to do this in Neo4j ? Or is it better to use a document based DB for that such as MongoDB?

Comment: Any database, SQL or NoSQL, will handle this easily.  "Best" is opinion based.  Neo4J is a graph database.  I can see a graph that starts with country, which has state children, which has city and zip children.  Those are tricky, because a city can have many zip codes.   I'd do the simple thing - put them in a relational database and move on.

Comment: The question is not if SQL or NoSql can handle this or not. Maybe, it was not clear. But, I'm using Neo4j already for my website. So, is it better to handle this functionality using Neo4j as well or better to handle in another db because of such and such reason/benefit. It is my first attempt trying to build something like that. Thought somebody who has more experience in this area could share his opinion

Comment: I understood the question.  I wouldn't put this in Neo4J.  Graph databases are best for deep object graphs.  That's not the case for your zip code data.   It's a simple matter for a relational database.  I'd put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason you can't do what you suggested, creating nodes for City, State, Country and wiring them up (I'm planning on doing this exact same thing with my upcoming project). This also lets you reuse those nodes in other parts of your graph, potentially allowing you to make interesting queries using common locations at faster speeds than property comparisons.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you'll have dropdowns or autocomplete fields or similar to drill down to each level (populate dropdown with countries -> populate next dropdown with states in the selected country -> populate last drop down with cities in the selected state). Just add indexes on identifier or abbreviation for quick node lookup and you're good, it should work quite fast.

If you're adding zip codes in there, that could be tricky, as you can't really model it in the same way. You'll have one-to-many relationships from both state and city to zip, and unless I'm mistaken there are a few interesting zips which can span more than a single state and/or city. Some other factors that can complicate things include 5 vs 9 digit zips (or more for other countries), and handling of zip-equivalents in other countries, as they may adhere to different logic.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible but to begin with I just avoided creating all 50,000 nodes when many of them might not even be used. I'm taking two step approach. I'm using flask framework, so I'll populate drop-down menus using csv files. I'll create nodes for City, state, Country when user submits the registration form. So, as you suggested I can re-use nodes in other parts of my graph. I'll didn't realize about your suggestion regarding adding indexes on identifier or abbreviation. I'll give that a go too and see if that works out better. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: The indexes will likely only be useful if you have a query where you start from a city (or state or country) and specify by some custom identifier or abbreviation, like a query regarding data for users from Detroit, or within California, or something. If you're starting from some other piece of data that has a single (or very few) relationship to City (or Country or State) then the indexing won't help much, since lookup and traversal of the linked node is already constant-time.